# How to test in htaccess if there is proxy?

Tags: .htaccess, if-statement, proxy

```
I've a htaccess that filters and redirects to a API a Moodle referer. "moodle.mysite.com"; works well with:
**RewriteRule ^. * $ /****/******.php [NC, L]** 
With "http (s): //mysite.com/moodle" , I get this: 
*The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. 
The proxy server could not handle the request GET/proxy8080/****/******.php. 
Reason: DNS lookup failure for: nodomainamen: 8080http:* 
But it works with 
'**RewriteRule ^. * $ /****/******.php?requete=%{REQUEST_URI}? [P]**' 
That's why I would like to test the presence of a proxy with a code like this:
"**RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]**"
# if no proxy
"**RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]**"
#elseif there is proxy
"**RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php?request=%{REQUEST_URI}? [P,QSA,NC]**"
```

I want to verify if the referer needs the proxy server and if it is, use [P] with trasferring %{REQUEST_URI} or not.
 Thanks for help

Comment: can you clarify your question? The question is unclear.

Comment: Thank you for this question
It is a htaccess that filters and redirects to a API a Moodle referer.
 "http://moodle.mysite.com"  works well with:"RewriteRule ^. * $ /****/******.php [NC, L]"
With 'http (s): //mysite.com/moodle' , I get this:
"The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request GET /proxy8080/****/******.php. Reason: DNS lookup failure for: nodomainamen: 8080http:"
But it works with
'RewriteRule ^. * $ /****/******.php?requete=%{REQUEST_URI}? [P]'
That's why I would like to test the presence of a proxy

Comment: there is `edit` function to update your question, and format the code to your question so that we can help